# Relative primeness of polynomials over extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider irreducible polynomials $f,g$ over $F[x]$ such that $(f,g) = 1$ over $F$ is it true then that $(f,g) = 1$ over some field extension $E$? What if they are not irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $F$ is a field. $(f,g)=1$ is equivalent to the existence of $u,v$ such that $uf+vg=1$ since $F[X]$ is a principal domain. Therefore, for every extension $E$ of $F$, $uf+vg=1$ and $(f,g)=1$ in $E[X]$.

Comment: Thanks, and is the converse true?